# tf.data.dataset from avro files

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I'm trying to parallelize my input pipeline using `tf.data.Dataset` and `TFRecordDataset`.

```
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("./data/*.avro")
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files, num_parallel_reads=16)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(
    preprocess_fn, 512, num_parallel_batches=16) )
```

I'm not sure how to write `preprocess_fn` if the input is an AVRO file (which is like JSON).

---

Currently, I am using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` and feeding it avro records parsed by `pyavroc` or similar avro readers. But I'm not sure how to parallelize this as `from_generator` method does not have `num_parallel_reads` option available.

```
def gen():
    for file in all_avro_files:
        x, y = read_local_avro_data(file)
        for i, sample in enumerate( x ):
            yield sample, y[i]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator( gen, 
            (tf.float32, tf.float64),
            ( tf.TensorShape([13000]), tf.TensorShape([]) 
        ) 
    )
```

Reading file by file is clearly a bottleneck and I see all cores waiting for data after exhausting the data from previous batch.

How to optimize either of the approaches?

Comment: Did you find the work around for your problem? Would be great if you could share any insights

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/a/52185891/1585523 useful. Ultimately, using TFRecords Dataset is the fastest w.r.t records / sec, however consumes more space

Comment: Thanks, ye right now I'm wondering should I even bother converting avro files into TFRecords, and then consuming TFRecords vs just using the avros directly in TF and implementing epochs + batching myself. (usecase is I'm converting SparkML jobs that used lots of Avros into TF jobs). If you have any insights on this front, It'd be great if you could share